# tclsoap and ssl

Tags: soap, https, tcl

Can anyone provide a working example of using tclSOAP with SSL? The links referred to in the official docs aren't working http://tclsoap.sourceforge.net I'm unsure how to configure the transport protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I'd post your question [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/topics).  The maintainers of TCLSoap are more likely to see it and respond to it.

Comment: Good idea - I'll give it a lash.